# what types of businesses or service providers must give concessionary pricing to those in benefits and/or disabled?

Tags: england-and-wales, disabilities, government-benefits

In England the practice is so widespread among various types of institutions that it must be not only rooted in some degree of societal tradition but also some statutory provisions of some sort. What is the origin of this practice?

Answer (score 4):

### Custom is more important than the law

AFAIK there is no legal requirement to provide concessional pricing for any goods or services.

Custom dictates that this is more common for services than for goods but, for example, cinema’s often don’t provide concessional pricing for blockbuster movies.